# Selenium 2 Java XPATH of all web elements in <body> tag in excel file

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, frameworks, automated-tests

Helloa everyone @Stackoverflow!! I searches through Stackoverflow but did not find the right solution. I am going to write the code about what I want to get, but asking here first to start with 'the right foot'.

Let's talk about what I'd like to obtain:

Given a webpage URL I need to find the absolute XPATH of all elements contained between -tags. The output of the code will be an ``.xls` file with three main columns.

```
WebElement type
CSS id or CSS class
absolute XPATH
```

In Selenium, I think I should:

```
getUrl of the webpage,
Ceate an array containing all the tags I want to extract ( a, p, form,input ... )
Iterating among all instances of each array tag extracting XPATH and writing in the .xls file all the data's while iterating.
```

I also think the best way to code it should be a method, is xPathExtract(URL,we) where URL is the page and we is the webElement. I read here about various answers to similar questions, but always not applicable to my idea.

So I am here to hear about suggestions on how to handle this in the best way and obviously I will keep track of everything here...

Thank you in advance.

CarloG